# How can I use isForwardRef correctly in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I try to use isForwardRef, but that doesn't work as expected.

how can I use that?

https://codesandbox.io/s/isforwardref-hs4zg?file=/demo.tsx

```js
import React, { forwardRef } from "react";
import { isForwardRef } from "react-is";

const Example = forwardRef<any, any>((ref, prop) => {
  return <div ref={ref}>123</div>;
});

export default function CircularDeterminate() {
  console.log(isForwardRef(Example));

  return <div>abc</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/d48dbb824985166ecb7b2959db03090a8593dce0/packages/react-is/src/ReactIs.js#L119-L121) of `react-is`:

```
export function isForwardRef(object: any) {
  return typeOf(object) === REACT_FORWARD_REF_TYPE;
}
```

it requires an object, not a React component itself of which it can check the type

Answer (score 0):

isForwardRef receives object as its parameter. Currently your are passing component instead of its object. To do that, pass it like this

```
  console.log(isForwardRef(<Example></Example>));
```

Also, ForwardRef receives prop as it first parameter and ref as it second parameter. Read more about [ForwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) here

```
const Example = forwardRef<any, any>((prop, ref) => {
  return <div ref={ref}>123</div>;
});
```